# $resource doesn't return value AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am really new to AngularJS (let's say 20hours of exp) , but still got the task being backend developer in Java.
Backend returns data for sure but below function doesn't get data. Can u tell me guys why? Or what should I check?

Api

```
function func2(id) {
   return $resource(URL + ':id/all', {id: id},
      {get: {method: 'GET', cache: true, isArray: true}})
      .query();
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
  // Simple Post request example:
```

var url = 'posturl', data = 'parameters',config='contenttype';

$http.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) {

// This function handles success

}, function (response) {

// this function handles error

});

Visit https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/angularjs/angularjs-http-post-method-http-post-with-parameters-example